# How to get specific time format in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, I have to perform CRUD operations based on the last date modified field.

```
DateLastModified

2021-09-09 16:46:05.670
....
```

In my SP, I am getting a date using getdate() function but it shows me the date something like this

```
set  @TodayDate = getdate()
```

```
May 17 2022  3:04PM
```

How can I get the date in the format shown below?

```
2022-05-17 15:04:00.113
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` doesn't return a formatted value, it returns a `datetime` value; which is a binary value with no formatting. Formatting is a task for the presentation layer, *not* the RDBMS. Assuming `@TodayDate` is a date and time value, then SQL Server will be able to pass the value as what it is, a date and time value.

Comment: If its within a SP, it seems unlikely you need to "See" it, so just carry on with your operations using the correct datatypes because as Larnu said, a datetime doesn't have a display format.

Comment: Adding to what @Larnu said, the "May 17 2022  3:04PM" display format is determined by the tool you use. SSMS and ADS will show datetime data with format "2022-05-17 15:04:00.113".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
select convert(varchar(23), getdate(), 21)
```

see the reference:
[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/#:~:text=How%20to%20get%20different%20date%20formats%20in%20SQL,use%20this%20T-SQL%20syntax%20SELECT%20CONVERT%28varchar%2C%20getdate%28%29%2C%2023%29](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20get%20different%20date%20formats%20in%20SQL,use%20this%20T-SQL%20syntax%20SELECT%20CONVERT%28varchar%2C%20getdate%28%29%2C%2023%29)

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Except you have kinda missed the point, OP is confused about a datetime having a format - so is unlikely to actually need to format it.

Comment: Maybe.  But the reporter just want to show the expected format.  In fact,  the format is decided by both the server side default format and the client side (driver) format option.

Comment: The [SQL] server has *no* control over the display format of a `datetime` value, @SeanH ; that is purely up to the presentation layer. What the above does doesn't return a formatted `datetime`, it returns a `varchar` representing a date and time value, which is *very* different. If you attempted to format that value in the presentation layer, it would have **no** affect. The `varchar` value `'2022-05-17 15:04:00.113'` formatted in the presentation layer using the style string `yyyyMMdd` would return the `varchar` value `'2022-05-17 15:04:00.113'`, *not* a date value `20220517`.

Comment: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuIdt.png) of prior described behaviour.

Comment: This will yield the same result as `SELECT GETDATE();`, won’t it? The problem is the OP is using `PRINT GETDATE();`.